# Session Identifier Not Updated

Tags: tcl, session-variables, session-cookies, owasp, project-open

I'm working on open-source application "Project-Open" and during the scanning I got the following vulnerability:

```
[Medium] Session Identifier Not Updated
Issue: 13800882
Severity: Medium
URL: https://<server_name>/register/
Risk(s): It is possible to steal or manipulate customer session and cookies, which might be used to impersonate a legitimate user,allowing the hacker to view or alter user records, and to perform transactions as that user
Fix: Do not accept externally created session identifiers
```

though the fix is mentioned but it is not sufficient for me to understand it completely.please guide me how should I remove this.Also let me know if any further details are needed to understand the question.
P.S. the code is in tcl

Comment: Not enough information. You found a vulnerability, but didn't mention in what kind of software.

Comment: [`]project open[`](http://www.project-open.com/) is a big suite of things; it's too hard for us to guess how to help with what you've said so far.

Comment: @DonalFellows let me know what else you want to know...